# Вектор в строку С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, vector

Как превратить вектор в число и перевернуть его на языке С++? В JS это делается вот так:

```
let num = Number([1, 3, 4, 5].reverse().join(''))
consolt.log(num) // 5431
```

То есть получается именно число. А для С++? Как например и вектора

```
vector<int> num = {1, 3, 4, 5};
```

Надо получить число

```
int res = 5431;
```

Числа в исходном векторе ТОЛЬКО однозначные.

Comment: А исходная задача именно так стоит ? Про вектор чисел? Не про число из цифр, которые надо перевернуть и получить число?

Comment: @vegorov Исходная задача — именно вектор чисел перевернуть и получить число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/my3zsy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector <int> num = {1, 3, 4, 5};
  stringstream ss;
  copy(num.rbegin(), num.rend(), ostream_iterator<int>(ss, ""));
  int res;
  ss >> res;
  cout << res;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так :)

Вариант, работающий даже с многозначными числами:

```
string revs(const vector<int>&n)
{
    return accumulate(n.rbegin(),n.rend(),r,
              [](string r, int x) { return r += to_string(x); } );
}
```

Если эти многозначные числа тоже надо развернуть - ну, это труднее:

```
string revs(const vector<int>&n)
{
    string r;
    return accumulate(n.rbegin(),n.rend(),r,
              [](string r, int x) {
                  string t = to_string(x);
                  reverse(t.begin(),t.end());
                  return r += t; } );
}
```

См. работающую программу [здесь](https://ideone.com/adFtqp).

Ну, а если нужно число (хотя в заголовке вы пишете "*в строку*") - то можно просто применить к полученной строке `stoll`.

Можно и проще, но непонятно, как именно обрабатывать многозначные числа. Если уточните, во что должен превратиться вектор, скажем, `{1, 23, 45670, 5}` - то поговорим :)

Для только однозначных чисел идеален как в смысле простоты, так и производительности метод @ARHovsepyan, который я, впрочем, переписал бы в одну строку:

```
int revs(const vector<int>&n)
{
    return accumulate(n.rbegin(),n.rend(),0,
              [](int res, int x) { return res = res*10+x; } );
}
```

в основном из-за того, чтов таком случае он применим практически к любому контейнеру (кроме `forward_list` и всех `unordered`, причем к последним - просто потому, что понятие порядка у них отсутствует).

Варианты предыдущий мой и @Qwertiy нужны для многозначных чисел, но оба страдают от лишнего преобразования - у меня в строку, у @Qwertiy - в строку, поток и опять в число...

Answer (score 0):

### Если в последовательности только одназначные числа, то одни из многих вариантов

вариант с вектором:

```
vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
int res{};
for (int i : v) {
    static int k = 1;
    res += i * k;
    k *= 10;
}
```

Но  в C++  есть оптимизированный  для численных методов очень удобный класс  `valarray` Вариант с ним будет короче и быстрее:

```
valarray<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5};
int res = valarray<int>(v1.apply([](int i)
{ static int k = 1; i *= k; k*= 10; return i;})).sum();
```

Если в последовательности  числа многозначны, то вариант не вмещать в int конкентацию более двух чисел, резко возрастает, поэтому я предложил только варианты для однозначных чисел

Comment: А как быть с многозначными числами?...

Comment: @Harry,  не понимаю, какая проблема с многозначными числами, если  в вопросе  говорится об  int res? Т.е. человеку нужно получать  число вмещающийся в int

Comment: Берем ваш код для `vector<int> v{12,34,56};`, получаем `5952`. Вряд ли это то, что хотел ТС...

Comment: @Harry, мой вариант с многозначными тоже работает (но не переворачивает их), правда, я там какую-то муть насоздавал...

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, он работает. Просто без точного ТЗ результат ХЗ. Ничего не сказано - например, сами числа разворачивать или нет... так что пока это так, гадание на кофейной гуще :)

Comment: @Harry, этот вариант не учтен,  но нетрудно написать и для  многозначных чисел, хотя я  уверен, что  в вопросе имеется ввиду именно  вектор с однозначными числами.

Comment: @Harry, js'ный код переворачивает массив до объединения в строку.

Comment: @Harry Да, в векторе будут только однозначные числа.

Comment: Тогда достаточно одной строки, как в вашем JS-варианте: `accumulate(n.rbegin(),n.rend(),0,
                  [](int res, int x) { return res = res*10+x; } );` - при этом будет работать не только с векторами (см. мой ответ).

Comment: @Harry, я конечно с вами согласен во всем, на что вы указали. Я  просто  пытался показать схожее  выражение  написанное в вопросе( мол,   C++  ничем не  уступает  JS).  Спасибо за ваши  замечания!

Comment: Коллеги, зачем вы все усложняете? Для однозначных чисел в векторе достаточно простого цикла от конца к началу